# Turn multiple fields into one phrase and use LIKE on it?

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty tricky question here,

I have a table with multiple fields. Right now, the WHERE clause in my query looks like this:

```
a.body like '%$v%' 
or a.model like '%$v%'
or a.other like '%$v%'
or s.name like '%$v%'
or w.name like '%$v%'
or b.name like '%$v%'
or p.name like '%$v%'
or c.name like '%$v%'
or o.name like '%$v%'
or cat.name like '%$v%'
```

All those field's are `VARCHAR(255)`, and `$v` would be the search term...

I'd like to take this query and perform a more accurate search. Right now it's giving undesired results.

I am just wondering, can I turn all of those fields into 1 big string search, or should I add fulltext indexes for all of them and do a match against all of them??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could perform an UNPIVOT and then perform the LIKE operation.

Comment: As What do you mean by *a more accurate search*? Can you elaborate? You showed code that produces inaccurate results, but you did tell a thing about how accurate results should look like to suit your needs.

Comment: well its unaccurate in that, lets say someone searches for "reebok skates", where reebok is an a.model, and skates is a p.name. well its matching all reebok or all skates the way it is now...

Comment: define **undesired results**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
WHERE CONCAT(a.body,a.model,a.other,s.name,w.name,b.name,p.name,c.name,o.name,cat.name) LIKE "%$v%"
```